# Why does the direct sum of infinitely many groups require only finitely many are nonzero?

Tags: group-theory, direct-sum, direct-product

Why does the direct sum of infinitely many groups require only finitely many are nonzero?

Is it just a case that the direct sum and direct product are two different things, and those are their names?  Or is there a logical connection between the idea of a sum and a product that governs one permitting infinitely many nonzero elements and the other not?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/523670/252641).

Comment: This is touched on in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum

Comment: @user1729 I read that thoroughly before asking and can't find the part addressing this question.

Comment: It's just a definition. I have also heard the direct sum referred to as the restricted direct product.

Comment: @DerekHolt It looks like the answers to the linked question explain it, e.g. "it doesn't make sense to consider *infinite sums*, because abelian groups don't have such an operation."  Not totally clear yet why infinite products *do* have such an operation but working on it...

Comment: The answer to your question is that "direct sum" and "direct product" are just names for two different constructions. You can ask why are they called that, just like you can ask why are groups called groups. But it sounds to me as though you will just confuse yourself unnecessarily if you try and understand why those names were chosen.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't want to hold myself back by giving up on understanding the underpinning motivation, because I think there are good reasons behind it, and understanding them properly will make me a better mathematician. I get the part where egreg says "we don't know how to sum an arbitrary family, but we *do* know how to sum finitely many terms." But I don't grasp why convergence is permitted for the infinite product. It would seem likely it's related to the idea $\prod_i(1+n_i):n_i\to0$

Comment: No, that is completely unrelated. First, direct sum is a term mostly used for abelian groups (and often called restricted direct product for arbitrary groups as Derek mentions). The part about summing is related to this being a universal construction in categories of modules, where we need to sum to get that property (for the direct product, the arrows will go in the other direction, so we don't have this problem).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft by the arrows going in the other direction do you mean instead of convergence "down" to some $x\times1$, they go "up" to modular equivalence classes?

Comment: No, sorry I mentioned that at all, that was a mistake. There is nothing related to convergence of any kind in the distinction between direct sum and direct product. If there was, people would have told you about it already, so there is no point to keep guessing at weird connections.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ok thanks. Perhaps you meant the morphisms in category theory flow the other way, which would at least give me an idea to pin on the words for now.

Comment: @RobertFrost Did you vote to close your own question? You can just delete it...

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes I did.  The duplicate question functionality is there for good reason... if someone makes a similar search to the title in my question, this directs them to the other question which has some really informative answers.  In fact the title of that question could be better. Perhaps that's why I never found it in a search

Comment: Chiming in here two years later to agree with @samerivertwice; I'd never have found the linked question with a google search for my original topic, but by using this question as a redirect I found it in five minutes. At the same time, there's no reason to actually have two duplicate answers on MathSE.