# Can both $f(P) = Q$ and $f(P_{\mathrm{sub}}) = Q$ hold when $f$ is a surjective group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

If $P$ and $Q$ are groups and $f: P \to Q$ is a surjective homomorphism, is it possible that $f(P) = Q$ as well as $f(P_{\mathrm{sub}}) = Q$ where $P_{\mathrm{sub}}$ is a *proper* subgroup of $P$? This should be an easy question but for some reason I'm just blanking out.

You can suppose $P$ and $Q$ are abelian groups, but I guess that doesn't affect the question. I'm thinking of this in the context of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/525836.

Comment: Of course it can. $P=S_3$, $Q=C_2\cong S_3/A_3$, $f$ the quotient map. Then the image of any $2$-element subgroup of $P$ is all of $Q$. For an abelian group example, take $f\colon C_2\times C_2\to C_2$ given by $f(a,b) = a$, and consider the two proper nontrivial subgroups that are distinct from the kernel. In general you are looking for proper subgroups $K$ such that $KN=P$, where $N=\mathrm{ker}(f)$, and in general there are many such subgroups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, that helps a lot. So I guess I'm confused about Martin's answer. He says that if there's a surjective group homomorphism $f: P \to Q$ and there's an injection $g: Q \hookrightarrow P$ and if $f\circ g = \mathrm{id}$ on the domain $Q$ then $P = Q$ ($Q$ was a subgroup of $P$, a priori). This should be a new question, but asking just in case you have a quick answer.

Comment: I think you have the composition reversed. $P$ is the coproduct; $Q$ is the subgroup generated by the images of the canonical inclusions. The inclusions yield a map $f\colon P\to Q$ induced by the inclusions. And the fact that it is a subgroup gives the map $g\colon Q\hookrightarrow P$. But this gives maps from the cofactors to $P$, $g\circ f\circ \iota$, which induces a unique morphism $P\to P$ making the relevant triangles commute, and this means that $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}$, because the identity also "works". This means $f$ is surjective, hence bijective as it was already  injective.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I get that $g \circ f$ is a unique morphism from $P \to P$ since both $f$ and $g$ are unique, but I don't get your argument for why $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}$. What can't $g \circ f$ be some other unique morphism apart from the identity morphism? And in what sense do we know that the "identity also works"?

Comment: I've replied to your question showing this. The uniqueness doesn't come from $g$ and $f$ each being unique, they come from the universal property of the coproduct. The **result** is unique, regardless of how you build it up. This is a common error. You cannot deduce uniqueness of the end result of a process from a decision to follow a particular path in which each step is uniquely determined, unless you also show that the path you choose is the *only* path available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can happen. You could take $Q$ to be the trivial group, and $f: P \rightarrow Q$ the trivial map, which is surjective. The image of any subgroup of $P$ under $f$ is clearly also $Q$.